# Error:Abnormal build process termination - Intellij 16.1.1, JDK 1.8.0_21

Tags: java, intellij

Esta é a primeira vez que estou usando `IntelliJ IDEA` e logo tive problemas pra compilar:

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: /home/nathanpb/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\"
```

Estou usando `Linux Mint Cinnamon 1.8`, alguns amigos me disseram que poderia vir de um `driver` problemático da `nVidia` (também encontrei essa afirmação enquanto pesquisava), mas estou usando uma versão mais antiga do `driver` (340.101-0ubuntu0.16.04.1). Para garantir, estou usando a placa da Intel, no `nVidia Prime`.

---

Estou tentando compilar [este projeto](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1OIzpv8SfPUQkp3VHRlS2Ryd2c/view?usp=sharing):

Tem como dependência `spigot-api-1.10.2-R0.1-20161012.085000-80.jar`
(https://www.spigot.org)

---

Acabei de tentar compilar um simples `System.out.println("Hello World");` e o mesmo erro acontece :c

---

Tentei atualizar a IDE, mesmo resultado.

---

Destaco que `"/home/nathanpb/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java"` não é um diretório, e sim um arquivo (veja comentários).

---

> nathanpb@nathanpb-Inspiron-3442 ~/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin $ javac -version
>   The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
>    * default-jdk
>    * ecj
>    * gcj-4.9-jdk
>    * openjdk-8-jdk-headless
>    * gcj-4.8-jdk
>    * gcj-5-jdk
>    * openjdk-9-jdk
>   Try: sudo apt install 
>   nathanpb@nathanpb-Inspiron-3442 ~/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin $ java -version
>   openjdk version "1.8.0_03-Ubuntu"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_03-Ubuntu-8u77-b03-3ubuntu3-b03)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.03-b03, mixed mode)
>   nathanpb@nathanpb-Inspiron-3442 ~/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin $

Comment: Link original da sua mensagem de erro: https://hastebin.com/etozujicuc.vbs

Comment: Qual foi o código que você tentou compilar?

Comment: Se você digitar `javac -version` no prompt/cmd, o que aparece como saída? Execute isso de dentro de `/home/nathanpb/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java`